# Не работает "My location" Google Maps

Tags: java, android, android-sdk

После выключения и повторного включения локации перестает работать (показывать) мою текущую геопозицию. Но когда я зайду в гугл карты после этого моя локация появляется (в моей программе). Спасибо за ответы.
Java code:

```
public class run2 extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {
BottomNavigationView bnv;
Location currentLocation;
FusedLocationProviderClient fusedLocationProviderClient;
private static final int REQUEST_CODE = 101;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_run2);

    fusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);
    getLastLocation();


}

private void getLastLocation() {
    if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]
                {Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},REQUEST_CODE);
        return;
    }

    Task<Location> task = fusedLocationProviderClient.getLastLocation();
    task.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Location location) {
         if(location != null){
             currentLocation = location;
             SupportMapFragment supportMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
             supportMapFragment.getMapAsync(run2.this);
         }
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(currentLocation.getLatitude(), currentLocation.getLongitude());
    MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title("I AM HERE");
    googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
    googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng,5));
    googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode){
        case REQUEST_CODE:
            if(grantResults.length>0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                getLastLocation();
        }
            break;
    }

}
```

XML code:

```
 <fragment
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    tools:context=".MapsActivity"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]